# Problem in where clause and aliases in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

What's wrong with this mysql query :

```
select * 
    from tpa as t1 
    where ( select count(*) 
                from tpa as t2 
                where t1.id = t2.id )
```

error :

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't1.id' in 'field list'
```

Comment: This query doesn't make much sense as written. What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: it's just a technical question.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I don't believe you can use an alias in the sub query. That said what are you trying to accomplish with this? Even if the alias worked that sub query would always return > 0. In other words the query would be the same without the where clause at all.

Comment: The query doesn't make much sense - once the subquery has evaluated, your asking "select * from tpa where 34"

Comment: I was going to try to fix it, but I have to agree with the others. The intention of the query isn't even clear in this case. And @Cfreak: you can definitely use aliases in sub queries (in other SQL at least)

Comment: @assembler This query is technically correct. Perhaps this query is not **exactly** (character by character) the same as your original query **or** field `id` does not exist in table tpa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, as Cfreak pointed out in comment, that the alias is not visible in the subquery.

I think also that you forgot to specify some condition for your `count(*)` result to be equal to some-number (or other condition):

```
select * from tpa as t1 
where
(
select count(*) from
(
select * from tpa
)
as t2
where t1.id = t2.c_id 
) = 1
```

Change "= 1" with any numery condition you like, or this would be a silly way to rewrite this much simpler query:

```
select distinct * from tpa
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, count(*) from tpa as t1
group by id

/*If you need a certain count.. add-*/
having count(*) > 2
```

You should not need to use a subquery in either case.